# Saving list entry in multiple lists

Tags: 2010, workflow

I have 6 different but similar lists created on the same SharePoint 2010 site to collect information with my team. I would like to create a workflow that automatically duplicates list items as they are being created in one of the 6 individual lists into one master list on the same site. I've tried setting up a workflow to copy from the original list to the master list, but have not had success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Are items copying over at all?  Are you sure the workflow(s) are firing?  You'll need 6 workflows, one on each of the individual lists, to make this work.

Comment: I have 6 workflows set up, one on each separate list to copy the "current item" to the master list. The workflows do not appear to be firing, although I have them set to start when an item is created.

Comment: That sounds like maybe your workflows have not been published to the server.  If there was a problem with the workflow logic it would create some error message like "Failed On Start, Retrying" or "Error Occurred"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the copy item requires to have both lists with the SAME field names and same amount of fields, if they are different you won't be able to copy the item.

if the field amount and names are different you should create a new item in the workflow and get the current item information

or, make all your lists and master list look the same.